# SQL INSERT only unique values in table without errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL script, I have about 200 plus entries with `INSERT` statement in them. My script looks like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles]
GO

INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
VALUES (44, N'HomePage', NULL, 8, N'Welcome to the app')
GO

INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
VALUES (45, N'LogIn', NULL, 8, N'Enter your assigned credentials')
GO

INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
VALUES (46, N'LogOut', NULL, 8, N'Come back soon')
GO

INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
VALUES (47, N'RedirectAbout', NULL, 8, N'About Us')
GO

INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
VALUES (48, N'Contact', NULL, 8, N'Consultation')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles] OFF
GO
```

There are more than 200 `INSERT INTO` statements here. If it was shorter I could do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [BH].[LanguageFiles] WHERE Id = 46)
    INSERT INTO [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) 
    VALUES (46, N'LogOut', NULL, 8, N'Come back soon')
```

However, that is not feasible in this situation with so many entries. What could I do instead to fix this?

At the moment, when I run this script I get the following error:

> Exception Message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Tbl_LanguageFiles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '[BH].[LanguageFiles]'. The duplicate key value is (46)

**SOLUTION**

Thank you for the answers everyone. One way of going about it was using `IF NOT EXISTS` however, that was looking to be very lengthy as I would have to write it for all 250 entries. I ended up copying this in Excel and using `CONCAT` to insert the `IF NOT EXISTS` statement before with its respective condition.

Comment: Why isn't it feasible to do the existence check on each statement? You can write a script to generate that check statement for each of your inserts.

Comment: How would I go about generating that script? That bit's new to me if you could help me with that I'd really appreciate it

Comment: You can insert all the data into a temp table and write not in while inserting into Actual table

Comment: Your error above is happening because there is already an existing record with ID 46 in target table? Or is it because multiple insert statements have that ID?

Comment: @shree.pat18 It's happening because a record with the same Id already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [BH].[LanguageFiles1]
AS 
SELECT * FROM [BH].[LanguageFiles]
WHERE 1=2;

GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles1] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) VALUES(44,N'HomePage',NULL,8,N'Welcome to the app')
GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles1] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) VALUES(45,N'LogIn',NULL,8,N'Enter your assigned credentials')
GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles1] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) VALUES(46,N'LogOut',NULL,8,N'Come back soon')
GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles1] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) VALUES(47,N'RedirectAbout',NULL,8,N'About Us')
GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles1] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value]) VALUES(48,N'Contact',NULL,8,N'Consultation')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles]
GO
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value])
SELECT [Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value] 
FROM LanguageFiles1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM [BH].[LanguageFiles])
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles] OFF
```

Comment: Temporary table syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` along with an exists clause, e.g.

```sql
INSERT [BH].[LanguageFiles] ([Id], [Key], [Secret], [LangId], [Value])
SELECT 44, N'HomePage', NULL, 8, N'Welcome to the app'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [BH].[LanguageFiles] WHERE Id = 44);
```

Comment: This is giving me the same error sadly.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Thank you for the answers, everyone. One way of going about it was using `IF NOT EXISTS` however, that was looking to be very lengthy as I would have to write it for all 250 entries. I ended up copying this in Excel and using `CONCACT` to insert the `IF NOT EXISTS statement before with its respective condition.